# Get training specifications for existing yolov5 model such as model version, image size and hyperparameters used during training

Tags: python, machine-learning, yolov5

I was wondering whether there is a way of getting information about how an existing custom yolov5 model was trained. For example, I would like to know the model version / release, on which image size the model was trained, and the hyperparameters used.

I was hoping for something like this:

```py
# load model
model = torch.hub.load('./yolov5', 'custom', path='./custom_model.pt', source='local')

# get train specifications
model.get_train_specs()

# Output:
#    Model version: 6.1
#    Trained on image size: 1280
#    Hyperparameters used during training:
#        lr0: 0.01
#        lrf: 0.2
#        momentum: 0.937
#        […]
```

Comment: It would help if it is known, from where the model was obtained, and if it had this data in the first place. The load primarily is just unpickling.

Comment: I would like to know for multiple models from different backgrounds. These are models trained on custom datasets by different users. However, they all used the yolov5 software to generate is. Does that help?